# I want to delete the curly brackets

Tags: education

```
Format[primeFactorForm[n_Integer]] := 
  Times @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n] /. _[x_] :> x;
block[n_Integer] := 
  Join @@@ Array[{#, primeFactorForm@#} &[# + 100*#2] &, {100, 
     10}, {1 + (n - 1) 1000, 0}];
grid[m_?MatrixQ] := 
  With[{th = AbsoluteThickness[1]}, 
   Grid[m, Dividers -> ({#, #} &@{th, {True}, th})]];
 sa =(*Print~Scan~*)Array[grid@block@# &, 2];
Style[sa, FontWeight -> Plain, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 6]
```

i want to delete the curly brackets

[image]

Comment: Wrap sa as Row[sa] or Column[sa]?  Presumably there is more than one element in sa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this[image]

```
 Format[primeFactorForm[n_Integer]] := 
  Times @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n] /. _[x_] :> x;
block[n_Integer] := 
  Join @@@ Array[{#, primeFactorForm@#} &[# + 100*#2] &, {100, 
     10}, {1 + (n - 1) 1000, 0}];
grid[m_?MatrixQ] := 
  With[{th = AbsoluteThickness[1]}, 
   Grid[m, Dividers -> ({#, #} &@{th, {True}, th})]];
 sa =(*Print~Scan~*)Array[grid@block@# &, 2];
Style[sa, FontWeight -> Plain, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 6][[1,1]]
```

[image]

Have fun!